# What is the term for a shape that has uniform dimensions?

Tags: geometry, circles, symmetry, spheres, square-numbers

Is there a term to describe a shape that has uniform dimensions?

**Squares** and **circles** would fall into this category for 2D shapes, as they are as wide as they are tall. Rather than ellipses or rectangles, since these can be wider than tall and vice verse.

Similarly, **cubes** and **spheres** would have this attribute for 3D shapes.

This term would also be quantitative. Some shapes would have more or less of this attribute.

Symmetrical comes to mind, but that doesn't seem accurate. For example, the shape of a tree is symmetrical, but often much taller than wide.

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

The phrase "uniform dimensions" is very vague, confusing, and open to numerous interpretations.

I *think* you're seeking [Meissner bodies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_of_constant_width), of which [Reuleaux triangles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reuleaux_triangle) are the most famous example.

See also [here](https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/CurvesAndSurfacesOfConstantWidth/).

---

As a mini-tutorial on how to ask better questions, *if* I understand your question, here would be a better way to state it:

**What is the mathematical term for a convex shape in $\mathbb{R}^n$ that spans the same maximum distance in one direction regardless of the orientation of that object?**

Comment: Consider the following, widely accepted definitions. Uniform: remaining the same in all cases and at all times; unchanging in form or character. Dimension: Any one of the three physical or spatial properties of length, area, and volume. In geometry, a point is said to have zero dimension; a figure having only length, such as a line, has one dimension; a plane or surface, two dimensions; and a figure having volume, three dimensions.

I am trying to learn what a 2D (or 3D) shape whose physical or spatial properties such as width and height (or depth) are the same in all cases would be called.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion toward convex shapes.  
Whether a shape is convex is irrelevant to the uniformity of it’s dimensional measurements. Both convex and non-convex shapes can have one dimension that is greater or lesser than the others, and vice verse.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion toward Reuleaux polygons.
A Reuleaux triangle would exhibit this trait (it’s height is equal to its width), whereas an equilateral triangle would not (while the length of all sides of an equilateral triangle are uniform, it’s dimensions are not). However, I’m not looking for a specific set of shapes, rather a term, or attribute, to describe if a shape has uniform dimensions or not.

(sorry for 3 comments, you provided 3 different directions to look at answering my question)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly what you describe is not at all something used in mathematics, that is an "intuitive" description that you want, not a mathematics thing.

I seem to have gotten two elements from your text:

- You don't want a shape wider than taller
- You want "uniform" shapes, but I am not sure what you mean by that

For the first one, one can say that it depends on the coordinate because you list "cubes" as one of those "uniform" shapes whatever that means. If you rotate the cube 30°, one side will be longer in a certain axis.

Therefore, what I understood, your criteria describes "shapes in N-dimension in an orthonormal basis that are invariant with rotation of 90° along the axis of the base".

Comment: “You don't want a shape wider than taller.” No. What I want to know is what shapes that are as wide as it they are tall area called…. Circles, squares, isosceles right triangles, equilateral octagons, etc. What I’m seeking is an attribute of a shape. Rotating the axes of the measurement system to alter it’s measurements wouldn’t actually change the shape, or any of its attributes.

Comment: “You want "uniform" shapes, but I am not sure what you mean by that”. No, my question clearly states that I want to know what shapes with “uniform dimensions” would be called. Uniform shape != uniform dimensions. A very irregular shape could be as wide as it is tall, and would thus have uniform dimensions, but would not be a uniform shape. (sorry about two comments, you gave two answers)

Comment: “not a mathematics thing”. Is geometry not part of mathematics? Is symmetry not an attribute that can be used to describe a shape defined by geometry? The attribute I am trying to learn about would be an attribute of a shape, similar to symmetry (or irregularity, or angularity, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

As @PackSciences says, this (vaguely expressed) property does not have an generally accepted name.

Perhaps you are interested in figures for which the bounding rectangle with minimum area is a square (or hypercube). Perhaps a hypercube with edges parallel to coordinate axes.

Comment: A hypercube could have this attribute if the measurement system used the same unit for all dimensions and all dimensions had the same value.