# Is there a mathematical term for shapes that have a degree of similarity in their dimensions?

Tags: geometry

Is there a term or way to describe 2 or 3 dimensional shapes that have similar or dissimilar dimensions, when oriented on a coordinate grid the shows the min and max measurements of the shape, and independent of how irregular it is - that is more elegant that just saying it is as tall as it is wide?

Some images to help illustrate my question.

A circle has identical height and width.
[image: circle]

A square also has identical height and width.
[image: square]

This irregualar shape also has identical height and width.
[image: irregular shape]

All of the above shapes have a high-degree of whatever this term or description would be.

This specific rectangle has a width that is twice its height. Of course, if rotated 45 degrees, it would measure with identical dimensions, but relative to itself, its dimensions are are dissimilar.
[image: rectangle]

This irregular shape has identical dimensions on the coordinate system it's measured on, but the shape itself does not have similar dimensions if rotated to orient it's max and min measurements so to reflect it's dissimilar measurements.
[image: irregular shape]

The latter two shapes have a low degree of similarity in their dimensions - relative to the shapes themselves, not the coordinate system their measured on.

I don't have an effective way to illustrate 3 dimensional objects, but this term or way to describe shapes could be applied to 3D objects as well.

For example, a rod that is `1 unit long x 1 unit wide x 1 unit tall` has a high degree of similarity in its dimensions. Compared to a rod that is `10 units long x 1 unit wide x 1 unit tall`, which has a lower degree of similarity in its dimensions.

Thank you

Comment: This is another attempt to ask the question : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3551806/what-is-the-term-for-a-shape-that-has-uniform-dimensions

Comment: Perhaps "inscribed in a square" roughly conveys the idea.  But only roughly.